# Add data to a many-to-many relationship using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, many-to-many

How can I Add data to a many-to-many relationship using Entity Framework? 
I have got a problem when I try to add one article with its related categories (see diagram), but the thing is that the categories already exist in the Categories Table, i don't need to create them again. When I use EF Method: _ctx.Articles.Add(newArticle), It generates insert sentences to categories table and duplicate my rows. Basically, I only need to add data to Article table and the reference table CategoryArticles. Add method, add rows to Article table (ok) plus Category table (wrong step) plus CategoryArticles table (ok).Any Idea How can I avoid to add these rows in my category table again.? Appreciate any help.

**EDIT: I AM USING AUTOMAPER FOR FILLING AN ARRAY OF CATEGORIES... I DO NOT IF MAYBE DOING IT ON THAT WAY I AM CREATING NEW OBJECTS. IT IS THE CODE:**

```
List<CategoriesViewModel> categoriesViewModel = article.CategoriesViewModel.Where(c => c.IsSelected).ToList();
List<Category> selectedCategories = Mapper.Map<List<CategoriesViewModel>, List<Category>>(categoriesViewModel);    

newArticle.Categories = selectedCategories;

_ctx.Articles.Add(newArticle)
```

This is the relational model

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Robert McKee, the way to solve the problem is to fetch the categories directly from the database, that way the entity framework automatically recognise these categories when the main entity is being saved, avoiding duplicate them.

Answer (score 0):

Many to Many relationships hide the cross reference table in EF.  The relationship model shouldn't show the CategoryArticles table at all.  The Articles table should have a "Categories" navigation property.  Just add a category to it, and save.

[image]

Comment: Hi Robert this what i am doing. I add a category to category property of article. The thing is that that category already exist in category table and it is ok. I dont need to create it again. I need to add the article and associate that category in the reference table. But Articles.Add(newArticle) create the article plus the category (this is the wrong, i alredy have that category there) and lastly it creates the row in the reference table (). I onlye need 1 and 3rd step.

Comment: Don't create a new Category, load the category from the database that matches and add it to the article.  Something like `var cat=db.Categories.First(c=>c.id==mycatid); myarticle.Categories.Add(cat);`  You can also try a library called GraphDiff (available on nuget) that can help you update completely detached entities to the database.

Comment: That's exactly what i am doing: 1. var cat=db.Categories.First(c=>c.id==mycatid); 2. myarticle.Categories.Add(cat); 3. Articles.Add(myarticle) // at this moment this add method creates the category again. Articles.Add(myarticle) genereate 3 inserts one for Articles another one for Category and one more for reference table. The second insert is what i want to avoid.

Comment: Well I am assigning my categories from a check list on my view. I am not getting the categories from the table again. I load a new array and assign it to the property categories on my Article Table like that: List<CategoriesViewModel> categoriesViewModel = article.CategoriesViewModel.Where(c => c.IsSelected).ToList();
List<Category> selectedCategories = Mapper.Map<List<CategoriesViewModel>, List<Category>>(categoriesViewModel);    
newArticle.Categories = selectedCategories;  Maybe is it wrong?

Comment: Sounds like your mapping in EF may be set up incorrectly then.  Sorry, not sure where to help you from here.

Comment: @DiegoBayona I've updated my answer with a partial view of my database model.  As you can see, I have Listings and Categories, and each Listing can have multiple Categories (indicated by the *-* relationship).  There is a ListingCategories table that is completely hidden that has `listing_id,category_id` as it's only fields.  Same for Tags.  There is a ListingTags table that is hidden that has `listing_id,tag_id`.